# Sort date strings in map

Tags: java, sorting, date, comparator

Hi I want to sort map objects based on dates below is the map

```
    testMap.put("06/15/2015", 1);
    testMap.put("05/15/2015", 2);
    testMap.put("01/15/2016", 4);
    testMap.put("07/15/2015", 3);
    testMap.put("02/15/2016", 5);
```

I need output like below sequence:

**05/15/2015 
06/15/2015
07/15/2015
01/15/2016
02/15/2016**

I need ouput like sorted months in 2015 and then starting 2016 months in sorted order

I have tried using treemap but it used to work if dates strings are in **Date** format, Can any one help in sorting as above sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom comparator for the `TreeMap`:

```
class DateComparator implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {

    public int compare(String date1, String date2) {
        int date1Int = convertDateToInteger(date1);
        int date2Int = convertDateToInteger(date2);

        return date1Int - date2Int;
    }

    // converts date string with format MM/DD/YYYY to integer of value YYYYMMDD
    private int convertDateToInteger(String date) {
        String[] tokens = date.split("/");

        return Integer.parseInt(tokens[2] + tokens[0] + tokens[1]);
    }
}

TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(new DateComparator());
```

This has the benefit of avoiding `Date` objects, which may slow `put` operations down.

Date strings like `06/15/2015` or `05/15/2015` are converted to comparable integer equivalents (`20150615` and `20150515` respectively) in keeping with their chronological order.

You can then add key/value pairs as usual, the keys will be ordered as per the comparator:

```
treeMap.put("06/15/2015", 1);
treeMap.put("05/15/2015", 2);
treeMap.put("01/15/2016", 4);
treeMap.put("07/15/2015", 3);
treeMap.put("02/15/2016", 5);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this right comparison of dates? It seems that you are just adding the integers and making up an integer and compare them !

Comment: Yes, `06/15/2015` becomes `20150615` , `05/15/2015` `20150515` and these integers are comparable.

Comment: Hacky but interesting. I can't seem to break it. Give me some time..may be I won't be able to ...

Comment: For this to work , you need to make sure that date matches the format that your comparator is expecting.

Comment: Nice!! but I am getting some issue. I have added below map

`treeMap.put("06/15/2015", 1);
treeMap.put("05/15/2015", 2);
treeMap.put("01/15/2016", 4);
treeMap.put("07/15/2015", 3);
treeMap.put("02/15/2016", 5)`

but In result I see only 

`{06/15/2015=3, 01/15/2016=5}`

Here I think there is problem if dates are same , I my case dates will be same :(

Comment: I fixed my code, some indexes were wrong in the comparator. If dates are the same, then the values are replaced. See the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29).

Comment: Its working !!! :) Thanks a lot @GentiSaliu

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by implementing a `Comparator<String>` and telling `TreeMap` about it when you create a new instance...

```
public class DateAsStringComparator implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {
   public int compareTo(String o1, String o2) {
     // Convert to Date and compare here.
   }      
}
```

And then...

```
final TreeMap<String, Integer> testMap = new TreeMap<>(new DateAsStringComparator());
```

(Code is untested but should give you an outline). Be sure to have your Comparator implement `Serializable` if you plan on serializing the `TreeMap`!

Comment: If I implement comparator interface I need to override all the methods present in that interface right?

Comment: Yes. It's a simple interface (two methods). And your IDE will probably write the `equals` method for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Todd's answer is right to use TreeMap, I just added the implementation of the comparator.
Better to delegate date comparison to "`compareTo`" methods built in `java.util.Date`

```
public class MyDateComparator implements Comparable<String>
{

    public int compareTo( String d1, String d2 )
    {
       if( d1.matches("\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}") && d2.matches("\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}") )
       { 
         //Valid date format
         String[] date_contents =  d1.split("/");
         java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date(date_contents[2], date_contents[0], date_contents[1] );
         date_contents =  d2.split("/");
         java.util.Date date2 = new java.util.Date(date_contents[2], date_contents[0], date_contents[1] );
         return date1.compareTo(date2);
       }

       return d1.compareTo(d2);
   }



});

Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(new MyDateComparator());
```

Comment: I can't help but feel this will end up creating a **lot** of Date objects, which would slow things down.

Comment: I understand, but you have to write complex comparison code that Date does.